# Where can I get a emulator image or binary info of NexusS?

Tags: android, android-emulator, nexus-s

I want to test some apps on Nexus S devices,
can I access the devices remote or get some emulator image for it?

for the GALAXY Tab, I could get it at http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do , but seems neither Samsung nor Google provides the actual info on Nexus S

Answer (score 4):

The Nexus S is pure Android.  You shouldn't need a special emulator for it, just use the standard emulator with SDK set to 2.3.  You can get all the details you need from the [tech specs](http://www.google.com/nexus/#/tech-specs).

Depending on what your app cares about, you probably just need to set the screen size appropriately: 4.0" WVGA (480x800)

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own AVD just like you did for the Galaxy Tab. Galaxy Tab had a special AVD because of its huge size.

[These](http://www.google.co.uk/nexus/#/tech-specs) are the nexus S specs. The Android version can be controlled by setting the minimum s/w version and api level.

In eclipse use this to create a new Virtual Device that has the same specs of Nexus S:

```
Window > AVD Manager
```